# Click event being fired twice

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS for the following component:

```
var TypeaheadBox = React.createClass({

_handleClick(e) {
    if (ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.typeaheadBox).contains(e.target)) {
        return;
    };
    this.props.onClickOutside();
},

componentWillMount: function() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this._handleClick, false);
},

componentWillUnmount: function() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this._handleClick, false);
},

render() {
    return (
        <div id='typeahead-box' ref='typeaheadBox'>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

As you can see, I'm adding a listener for a click event. When debugging, I realized that the _handleClick function is being called twice when a click event occurs, what's more in the second call the field *this.refs* is empty, so an error is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how many times did `componentWillMount` is getting called

Comment: it's also being called twice. Come to think of it, I'm using this component twice in my page.

Comment: that is why `_handleClick` is called twice.. each time `componentWillMount` is called it adds a new click handler to the documetn object